# Matplotlib graph in tkinter app: how to change graph visuals

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am integrating a Matplotlib graph in a Tkinter app; although I am having problems to port the formatting of the graph.

I am using the MPL tutorial as starting point; and I did notice that I cannot add `set_legend()` for example, or I can't pass the angle at which I would like the ticks on the x axis with `set_xticks(x, rotation=80)` and similar

How do you pass these parameters? Or the amount of changes that you can actually execute on a graph in a tkinter app is limited?

This is the example code that I am modifying:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk


def destroy(e):
    sys.exit()

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(s)
a.set_title('Tk embedding')
a.set_xlabel('X axis label')
a.set_ylabel('Y label')
a.set_xticks(t, rotation=45)


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=sys.exit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: If it can be done, it can be done with in the context of a tk app.  You just have to use the OO way instead of the staefull pyplot way (the OO way actually has way _more_ power).

Comment: Could you please elaborate further; this is the first time that I put together matplotlib and tkinter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get your example running: Axes has the method `.set_xticklabels` to set the ticklabels and `.legend()`to create a legend (some label must be set in the plot first).

```
f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(s, label="label")
a.set_title('Tk embedding')
a.set_xlabel('X axis label')
a.set_ylabel('Y label')
a.set_xticklabels(t, rotation=45)
a.legend()
```

In general, you are operating on instances of classes here. 
`f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)` creates an instance of `Figure`. This instance has a method `add_subplot` which returns an instance of `axes`, called `a` here. (Usually one uses `ax` instead). And `a` now has all the methods available for plotting, as can be read in the [`axes` API documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)

Comment: Wow, very not intuitive; the name is not set_xtick, but set_xticklabel; and legend goes without the set; thanks!

Comment: I agree that the differences in naming between the pyplot state machine and the object oriented API are not very intuitive. But mostly you'll find what you need in the search engine of your choice by looking for "pyplot + command" for the state machine or "matplotlib axes + command", sometimes "matplotlib figure + command" for the OO interface.